# how to hot plug an interface to a running guest domain in python via libvirt module?

Tags: python, libvirt

Scenario: I am working on centos 7 with python libvirt module. I have running guest domain here in centos 7. Now i want to attach an interface to this guest domain using python script. Initially there was no interface attached to the guest domain. XML file of guest domain doesn't contains any interface tags and all.

Using shell commands I am able to attach interface. I am calling this

virsh detach-interface --domain link01 --type bridge --mac 96:5c:34:c0:5d:09 --persistent

command in python script to attach the interface and it is successfully attached.
How to achieve this in python??

Any suggestions related to this will be of great help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two functions in libvirt.virDomain, that perform device attachment:

```
attachDevice(xml)
attachDeviceFlags(xml, flags=0)
```

See their documentation for details.
You can take a predefined interface stanza from a domain's config as a sample and should omit or edit the "address" and "mac" tags to avoid conflicts.

```
#generate or read your xml
import libvirt
conn = libvirt.open(name)
domain = conn.lookupByName(domain_name)
domain.attachDeviceFlags(xml, libvirt.VIR_DOMAIN_AFFECT_LIVE)
#or
domain.attachDevice(xml)
```